# Having problems initializing DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

A very green and inexperienced coder here.

I've been reading up on [DataTables](http://datatables.net/), a Plugin for the jQuery JS library, and I've been trying to implement a simple table. The problem is, I don't think I'm initializing the DataTables correctly.

I placed this block of code(that initializes the table) on the head tag of my page:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').dataTable();
 });
```

I believe I might be wrong in doing so. Where should I put this code?

I've been scouring the internet for any possible tutorials or beginners' guides, but it seems that there aren't any.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's fine where it is. But what about your actual table? Where is it? What trouble do you have with initialization?

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to import the datatables.js or jquery.js files?

Comment: The actual table is in the html file. I already have the datatables and the jquery files in the same directory as the html file of the page in question.

As for the initialization problems, the page just displays the table like a normal table in html, instead of displaying the data in DataTables(with pagination, next and previous buttons, etc). Did I answer your question correctly?

Comment: Yes. Did you import the relevant libraries *before* the initialization script? Because the way you describe it that sounds like the problem

Comment: Also, it's probably a good idea to share some more of your code. We'll be able to help you better without asking more questions

Comment: Uh. It looks like I fixed the problem. It seems that I put the block of code in the head tag, but outside of a script tag. Very basic error, I'm afraid. :(

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you to put that code in an external .js file and link it in your page inside your head tag of your page as below:

```
<head>
   ... import jquery lib ...
   <script type="text/javascript" src="yourScriptFile.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: He doesn't have a problem with what convention to use. This is not a solution to his problem, and a confusing suggestion for a newbie

Comment: @yuvi his code is extremely simple, so I suggested it for ensure correct imports. It was helpful.

Comment: You're suggestion focused on an irrelevant point so it's confusing and hinting that the problem is with running the script inside the HTML (which isn't)

Comment: @yuvi last spam msg: the problem is focused on where he put the script, my suggestion helped him (as he thanks me).

Comment: No, the problem was elsewhere. Read the comments on the question, he solved it himself